# Publishing a free app on WP8 store then make it not free

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I need help with publishing an app me and my team developed. It currently is in beta phase and we need testers. We thought of publishing it in the store as an open free beta app and ask for people to download it and report their bugs. After all the testing bugs are fixed the app will go public as v1.0 but not as free. We do however want the people who originally downloaded it to get all the updates for free as a reward for their help of testing our help and never have to pay for the app. How can that be done?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the WP8 store


Comment: I think its a very reasonable question and i would like to know the anwser! Can someone use Trial mode, In-App purchaces to solve it or is he forced to release a different beta app first and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know Beta App is different than 'Normal' App - so after finished test you need to publish new application (you can't change beta to normal).
What you are asking is called [targeted distribution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj619160%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - you can hide App (you will need to submit one more App for that purpose) from users browsing the store, and send a link to those who you choose (Beta testers). But you cannot prevent such a situation when a beta tester send this link to other person. So you have to cosider it.
**EDIT**
You cannot do such a thing like in beta version - create a list of user that will be able to use it.
The other solution that comes to my mind - you can create 'Beta' App that is the same as Normal App and alow specific user to use it. The disadventage of this method is that Beta expires after 90 days.

Comment: There is list of your beta-testers emails, so if someone who had email whicn isn't included in your list, he wouldn't be allowed to download your app.

Comment: no I would like it to be a public beta....... For example, launch it in the store, let anyone who wants download it, report their bugs, and when it is all fixed, update it, make it a paid app, and all who downloaded it as free will still get it for free

Comment: @Chepene But the list is only available when it's a beta version, for normal version you can only hide it.

Comment: @Romasz Yeah, I had written about Beta

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Beta version can have up to 10000 beta testers, but you have to add them.

Comment: @John Why not publish your app as free? You can change price at any time you want

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Chepene is right - it may be only way to 'public beta' - the disadventage is that you need to pass a certification which takes time (for normal App usually up to 5 working days). Your first users will be beta testers and as they downloaded your App for free, they won't have to pay after you change the price.

Comment: In beta you need only pass autocertification. Usually it takes 2-12 hours.

Comment: @Chepene changing the price will not affect people who already downloaded it? That is my main concern, everyone who downloaded for free will get the update after the price is changed

Comment: @JohnDemetriou You cannot chargé user for updates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442301(v=vs.105).aspx (changing price is an update) - so it won't affect people who downloaded it for previous price

Comment: @John, I'm not try it by myself, but I'm quite sure: If someone downloaded full version of your app, he will receive all updates.
Nobody will force to pay when you release new version of your app (we talk about your app's price, not about in-app purchases).
For example, I had downloaded a game when it were free (sale), and then creators set price for 3 dollars, but I don't care about it. I can сcontinue playing it for free. I can also remove it and then install again (for free, because I had already paid).